# Mongo shell aggregation pipeline error: "unknown operator: $nor"

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying aggregation pipelines for the first time on Mongo Shell following [this](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about) course. The idea is to create a search query with multiple conditions and use it within a `$match` aggregation stage.

My aproach was writing the conditions individually and combining them in an object like this:

```
let fullQuery = {
   "languagesQuery" : {
                "languages" : {
                        "$all" : [
                                "English",
                                "Japanese"
                        ]
                }
        },
        "genresQuery" : {
                "$nor" : [
                        {
                                "genres" : "Crime"
                        },
                        {
                                "genres" : "Horror"
                        }
                ]
        },
        "imdbRatingQuery" : {
                "imdb.rating" : {
                        "$gte" : 7
                }
        },
        "ratedQuery" : {
                "rated" : {
                        "$in" : [
                                "PG",
                                "G"
                        ]
                }
        }

}
```

The thing is that, while individually all the queries seem to work fine, when I run the pipeline or even `db.movies.find(fullQuery)` I get the following error:

```
Error: error: {
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1618483194, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "unknown operator: $nor",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1618483194, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"LPVJIin4JoThWZbFICVnzHOnJKU="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6902062171803353090")
                }
        }
}
```

Any clue as to what may be happening?

Comment: `$nor` does not exist in Mongo. Use `{$not: {$or: ...}}` or "not in" `{$nin: ["Crime", "Horror"]}`

Comment: $nor does exist, you can check the documentation for it in the comment below

Comment: `$match` is an [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) operator. In Aggregation `$nor` does not exist. You mixed it with [Query and Projection Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) Maybe compare [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) with [$gte(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/ is an expression-level operator, e.g. you can give it on top level of a query to combine clauses. It is not defined as a field-level operator.

For your query, use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/.

The rest of your query looks problematic also in that you should probably be using dot notation for conditions on nested fields and not nesting the fields in the query as you have done.